# sql syntax error while executing query (sql injection)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-error-1064

**QUERY:**

```
    model.client.query("SELECT ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians(longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + sin( radians(:latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude) ) ) ) AS distance FROM offers where  isActive= :isActive ",{'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude,'isActive':1},function (err,rows) {
        console.log(err);
});
```

**ERROR**

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians(longitude ) - radians(:' at line 1
```

Comment: The parameters are not getting substituted into the query.

Comment: that i understood, why it is not happening?

Comment: If you new that this is the reason for the MySQL error, then why did you not share this with us? In this case why is the exact MySQL error and in general MySQL relevant to this question?

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? LIMIT ?, 5',[ user_id, start ],  like this way

Comment: latitude occuring 2 times , then how can we do it with this method

Comment: It's really hard to read a 370+ character line of SQL. Tidy it up, post it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and then I'm sure someone will be able to help you with that. But don't post unreadable code and expect others to tidy it up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 model.client.query("SELECT ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians(longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( latitude) ) ) ) AS distance FROM offers where  isActive= ? ",[latitude,longitude,latitude,isActive],function (err,rows) {
        console.log(err);
});
```